# laravel use old() on input in view PHPUnit request return status 500

Tags: laravel, phpunit

why when i use old()

```
<input value="{{ old('c_age') }}" type="text" name="c_age" >
```

PHPUnit Test

```
public function testMember()
   {
    $response = $this->call('GET', 'member');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
  }
```

I run test fail because $response->status() return 500.
when I remove old() run test success.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Be more specific....

Comment: i have update in new post